# jquery onblur empty textbox validation on asp:textboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a series of asp:textboxes (about 30) which I wanted to validate if they are empty (when the user goes to other textbox), when the users leave them empty (on blur) I have found tutorials on the net however it is specified only to a few textboxes, how can I achieve this?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox ID="txtLname" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C2C4CC" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="28px" Width="135px" title="Enter Your Last Name" onkeypress="return AllowAlphabet(event)" Enabled="False" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Do you have Validators?

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of your actual markup would come in handy, but from the information i have:

```
$('input, textarea').blur(function() {
if ($(this).val() == "") alert("empty!");
});
```

> when the users leave them empty (on blur) I have found tutorials on
>   the net

How is this a sentence?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLname" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C2C4CC" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="28px" Width="135px" title="Enter Your Last Name" onkeypress="return AllowAlphabet(event)" Enabled="False" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: the asp code is not interesting, how is the markup being output? does my code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function CheckEmptyCheckBox() {
        var empty = 0;
        $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
           if (this.value == "") {
               empty++;
               $("#error").show('slow');
           } 
        })
       alert(empty + ' empty input(s)')
    }
```